# Multiple configurations for vhosts when using ejabberd with the mod_post_log module

Tags: configuration, module, erlang, virtualhost, ejabberd

I'm currently trying to get ejabberd working when using the mod_post_log module. I have defined two virtual hosts and I want some vhost-specific module configuration. My approach is the following in the `ejabberd.yml` file:

```
append_host_config:
  "host1.com":
    modules:
      mod_post_log:
        url: "http://host1.com/ejabberd_post_message"

append_host_config:
  "host2.com":
    modules:
      mod_post_log:
        url: "http://host2.com/ejabberd_post_message"
```

I expect this to work but it doesn't. According to the logs, `mod_post_log` cannot find the url option.

It works fine however if I define the following in the `~/.ejabberd-modules/mod_post_log/conf/mod_post_log.yml`:

```
modules:
  mod_post_log:
    url: "http://host1.com/ejabberd_post_message"
```

But this only works for one host.

So I'm not sure why the approach I tried is not working. Is there anyone who can clarify this and see what I'm doing wrong? I believe that I'm defining two seperate configurations for the `mod_post_log` module but apparently there's something incorrect here.

Comment: Which version of ejabberd are you using ? What do you have in logs ?

Comment: I've the same problem on version 16.06. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: What happens when you join the two `append_host_config` statements into one, i.e., deleting the second `append_host_config:` line? (It might be that the second entry overrides the first, and is not merged.)